# Why are there dynamic memory allocation in class and main() function too

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, allocation

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

class Employee
{
private:
    char *firstName;
    char *lastName;
    static int count;
public:
    Employee( const char * const first, const char * const last){
        firstName = new char[ strlen( first ) + 1 ];
        strcpy( firstName, first );

        lastName = new char[ strlen( last ) + 1 ];
        strcpy( lastName, last );

        count++;
        cout << "Employee constructor for " << firstName
             << ' ' << lastName << " called." << endl;
    }
    ~Employee(){
        cout << "~Employee() called for " << firstName
             << ' ' << lastName << endl;

        delete [] firstName; // release memory                                                                     
        delete [] lastName; // release memory                                                                      
        count--;
    }
    const char *getFirstName() const{
        return firstName;
    }
    const char *getLastName() const{
        return lastName;
    }
    static int getCount(){
        return count;
    }
}; // end class Employee                                                                                           

int Employee::count = 0;

main(){
    cout<<"Count = "<<Employee::getCount()<<endl;
    Employee *e1Ptr = new Employee( "Ahmad", "Ali" );
    Employee *e2Ptr = new Employee( "Saeed", "Khalid" );
    cout<<"Count = "<<e1Ptr->getCount()<<endl;
    cout << "\n\nEmployee 1: "
         << e1Ptr->getFirstName()<<" "<<e1Ptr->getLastName()
         << "\nEmployee 2: "
         << e2Ptr->getFirstName()<<" "<<e2Ptr->getLastName()<<"\n";
    delete e1Ptr;
    e1Ptr = 0;
    delete e2Ptr;
    e2Ptr = 0;
    cout<<"Count = "<<Employee::getCount()<<endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Q- Why do we need dynamic memory allocation in main() and in class as well? Is it not adequate to allocate dynamic memory either in class definition or main() function?

Q- Why e1Ptr = 0;and  e2Ptr = 0; is being used.

I am newbie. So, kindly elaborate a bit in detail. Thanks

Comment: Forget C. C++ is a completely different language.

Comment: OK. but in the above code, why cannot we create simply objects and pass the values to constructor. What is the need of dynamic memory allocation in main() function?

Comment: There isn't any need for it … That's just bad programming. …. PS: `main` requires a return type of `int` in C++

Comment: oh yes main has a return type int. thanks to indicate

Comment: Make sure to indent your code properly before posting. I have fixed it for you now.

Comment: In C++, you should use always use smart pointers (eg. std::unique_ptr, std::shared_ptr, ...) instead of manually allocating memory. Read this: https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers

Comment: Read a [good C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html), then the C++11 standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) then the documentation of your C++ compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It's rarely necessary to read the standard directly. A good book should suffice.

Comment: @LHLaurini. I definitely agree. But a lot of practice is also needed. See http://norvig.com/21-days.html

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. `new Employee( "Ahmad", "Ali" )` allocates memory for and initializes an instance of the `Employee` class and `new char[ strlen( first ) + 1 ];` allocates a string, inside the class.

That's, however, terrible C++ code. You should rarely manage memory directly, but instead use classes to aid you. These are called smart pointers and will automatically allocate, initialize, destroy and deallocate as needed. Managing raw pointers by hand is bug-prone and unnecessary. Remember: the less code you write, the less places you'll have for possible bugs.

Therefore, instead of

```cpp
Employee *e1Ptr = new Employee( "Ahmad", "Ali" );
```

you'd use

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<Employee> e1Ptr = std::make_unique<Employee>("Ahmad", "Ali");
```

or

```cpp
auto e1Ptr = std::make_unique<Employee>("Ahmad", "Ali");
```

and drop the `delete`.

Also, instead of allocating a string, you can use `std::string`. So instead of

```cpp
char* firstName = new char[ strlen( first ) + 1 ];
strcpy( firstName, first );
```

you'd use

```cpp
std::string firstName = first;
```

(and also drop the `delete[]`)

Comment: Okay, my question is if "new Employee( "Ahmad", "Ali" )"" allocates memory for and initializes an instance of the Employee class. It means that object has already been created and initialized as well here. So, what is the need of constructor here to initialize an object here and a string dynamic memory?

Comment: @RizwanMuzaffar Each `new` in main creates an instance of the `Employee` class. Each `new` in the constructor creates an array of char. So you end up with two instances of the `Employee` class (`*e1Ptr` and `*e2Ptr`) and four arrays of char (`e1Ptr->firstName`, `e1Ptr->lastName`, `e2Ptr->firstName` and `e2Ptr->lastName`), two for each `Employee`. But again, **do not allocate memory directly unless you have a reason to do so**. I definitely recommend you to find a good C++ book or tutorial. Remember, C and C++ are different languages: avoid anything labeled "C/C++".

Comment: What is the need of this statement?                 e1Ptr = 0;

Comment: @RizwanMuzaffar Not much, but it avoids accidentally dereferencing the pointers you just freed (it's easier to debug a crash if the pointer is null). Also, while it still works, it's better to use `nullptr` for that. Again, if you used `std::unique_ptr`, you wouldn't have to care about it.